# Always getting blank page on all Laravel routes

Tags: php, laravel

I am always getting blank page while accessing my Laravel project given below. Please advise how this problem can be resolved. Thanks!

http://1.231.118.4:9000/

http://1.231.118.4:9000/admin/login

Apache 2.4
PHP 7.2
MySQL 5.7

phpinfo: http://1.231.118.4:9000/info.php

vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:9000>
    ServerName 1.231.118.4
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ico/public
    <Directory /var/www/html/ico/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
     </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/ico/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Nothing in your `storage/logs/laravel.log`?

Comment: It is empty. No error log anywhere.

Comment: Obviously, some things work like for example your 404 page is not a typical boilerplate webserver 404 page and PHP is running based on your server configuration, so I'm guessing that is your own code, therefore, I don't think this is a server configuration issue but rather a code issue.

Comment: I am deploying the same code on different version. The same version of code is running on other server. Is there any way to figure out the problem?

Comment: Can you upload your project folder structure screenshot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php file, the routes were serviced on 443 port that's why I was getting 404 on all routes. Thanks everybody anyways.

```
    public function map()
    {
        switch(request()->getPort()){

          case 9001:
                //exit;
              break;
          case 443:
              $this->mapAdminWebRoutes();
              $this->mapApiRoutes();
              $this->mapWebRoutes();
              break;
         // choose a port that is not used by another server
          default:
          $this->mapAdminWebRoutes();
              $this->mapApiRoutes();
              $this->mapWebRoutes();
              break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue and it turned out that all codes in my index.php file in public directory was commented ! you can give it a try

Answer (score 0):

In my case, .env file had an entry with bad format, since spaces are not allowed in values without quotes for all value:

```
#BAD
DATETIME_FORMAT=Y-m-d H:i:s
#GOOD
DATETIME_FORMAT="Y-m-d H:i:s"
```

For some reason this error did not output anything nowhere, hope will be useful to someone with the same problem!